# split and flatten nodes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, split, nested, flatten

I cannot have any nested spans, so I need to flatten them and concatenate their class attributes so I can track which classes are parents.

Here's a simplified **input**:

```
<body>
    <h1 class="section">Title</h1>
    <p class="main">
        ZZZ
        <span class="a">
            AAA
            <span class="b">
                BBB
                <span class="c">
                    CCC
                    <preserveMe>
                        eeee
                    </preserveMe>
                </span>
                bbb
                <preserveMe>
                    eeee
                </preserveMe>
            </span>
            aaa
        </span>
    </p>
</body>
```

Here's the **desired output**

```
<body>
    <h1 class="section">Title</h1>
    <p class="main">
        ZZZ
        <span class="a">
            AAA
        </span>
        <span class="ab">
            BBB
        </span>
        <span class="abc">
            CCC
            <preserveMe>
                eeee
            </preserveMe>
        </span>
        <span class="ab">
            bbb
            <preserveMe>
                eeee
            </preserveMe>
        </span>
        <span class="a">
            aaa
        </span>
    </p>
</body>
```

Here's the closest I've come (I'm really new to this, so even getting this far took me a long time...)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/span">
      <span class='{concat(../../@class,../@class,@class)}'>
           <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
       </span>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see the result of my failed attempt and how far it is from what I really wanted if you run it yourself. Ideally, I'd like a solution that accepts an arbitrary number of nested levels and can also handle interrupted nests (span, span, notSpan, span...).

edit: I have added tags inside the nested structure per request by commenters below. Also, I'm using XSLT v1.0, but I could use other versions if needed I suppose.

edit 2: I realized that my example was over-simlified compared to what I actually need to convert. Namely, I cannot lose classes from other tags; only spans can be combined.

Comment: This may be more complicated that it appears: can a span contain nodes other than text? You speak of "interrupted nests", but where should the interrupting nodes go?

Comment: Yes, a span can contain other (notSpan) nodes and should be preserved if possible (inside their parent span node). Basically, interrupting nodes should be treated as if they were not nodes at all (as if they were plain text).

If the only solution cannot achieve this, I think I can have other nodes be divided as well.

Comment: I am afraid I don't really understand your answer. Perhaps you should expand your example to show the different scenarios

Comment: True, when you are creating a `span` for every text() inside span, you should really explain how the other elements are to be preserved. Also mention the XSLT version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the opening comments, this is far from being trivial. Here's another approach you may consider:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|.//span/text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span/text()">
    <span>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::span">
                <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::text())">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </span>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is to a large extent similar to what was suggested earlier by Lingamurthy CS - but you *will* see a difference with the following test input:

**XML**

```
<body>
    <h1 class="section">Title</h1>
    <p class="main">
        ZZZ
        <preserveMe>0</preserveMe>
        <span class="a">
            AAA
            <span class="b">
                BBB
                <span class="c">
                    CCC
                    <preserveMe>c</preserveMe>
                </span>
                bbb
                <preserveMe>b</preserveMe>
            </span>
            aaa
        </span>
        <preserveMe>1</preserveMe>
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following stylesheet helps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Identity transform template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | text() | .//text()[parent::span]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[parent::span]">
        <span>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:call-template name="class-value"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::text()) and not(self::span)]"/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="class-value">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::span/@class">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This gets pretty close. It does however duplicate all of the old tags outside of each correctly flattened span. I can fix it with some Regex until I figure out how to fix it... Do you have any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: @DocBuckets  "*It does however duplicate all of the old tags outside of each correctly flattened span.*" I don't see that it does that. Are you getting a different result than the one here: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwu ?

Comment: It did when I tried it on my real markup, but now I realize it's due to the `<xsl:template match="/p">` designation in line 12. My real files have other parent tags, so I had to adjust the code accordingly. I will test it again at work tomorrow and accept the answer if it ends up working.

Comment: @michael.hor257k unfortunately I oversimplified my MWE, not realizing that I was losing class attributes from non-span tags. I have updated my MWE to better reflect my actual problem. I will toy with it some more tomorrow.

Comment: @DocBuckets no worries, I've updated my answer and this would do for your updated input.

Comment: I think you are losing elements that should be preserved, if they appear as direct children of `p` (as in the modified input in Michael's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are .. I've did it recursively by nested-span template which take two params, the first is the current span class to concatenate the classes and the current span node.  Then process the nested spans.

So I just call the template for the root spans in our case the **span** under **p** tag.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <hmtl>
    <body>
    <p>
    <xsl:for-each select='.//p/span'>
        <xsl:call-template name='nested-span'>
            <xsl:with-param name='cclass' select='./@class'></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name='cspan' select='.'></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
    </body>
  </hmtl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


 <xsl:template name="nested-span">
        <xsl:param name='cclass'/>
        <xsl:param name='cspan' as='node()' />
        <span>
                <xsl:attribute name='class' select='$cclass'/>
                <xsl:value-of select='$cspan/text()[1]' />
                <xsl:if test="not(exists(./span))">
                    <xsl:if test='string-length($cspan/text()[2]) &gt; 0 '>
                         <xsl:value-of select='$cspan/text()[2]' />
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[local-name() != 'span']"/>
                </xsl:if>
        </span>

        <xsl:for-each select='$cspan/span'>
            <xsl:call-template name='nested-span'>
                <xsl:with-param name='cclass' select='concat($cclass, ./@class)' ></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name='cspan' select='.'></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>


        <xsl:if test="exists(./span)">
            <span>     
                <xsl:attribute name='class' select='$cclass'/>
                    <xsl:if test='string-length($cspan/text()[2]) &gt; 0 '>
                        <xsl:value-of select='$cspan/text()[2]' />
                    </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[local-name() != 'span']"/>
            </span>
        </xsl:if>    
</xsl:template>
```

And here's the output

```
<hmtl>
   <body>
      <p>
            <span class="a">
             AAA
            </span>
            <span class="ab">
               BBB
            </span>
            <span class="abc">
              CCC
              <preserveMe>
                eeee
              </preserveMe>
            </span>
            <span class="ab">
               bbb
               <preserveMe>
                  eeee
                </preserveMe>
            </span>
            <span class="a">
              aaa
            </span>
       </p>
   </body>
</hmtl>
```

I hope this could help

Comment: Doesn't look like this will work for more than 2 text nodes in `span`.

Answer (score 0):

As you said XSLT 2.0 *could* be a viable option, I tried an approach based on node grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="* | @* | text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="* | text()" group-adjacent="name() = 'span'">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-group()/self::span">
                    <!-- a group of span elements: nothing to do yet -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- a group of text nodes and no-span elements: create span -->
                    <span class="{string-join((ancestor::span/@class), '')}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </span>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Salient points:

- children of a `span` element, both text nodes and other elements, are grouped based on whether they are `span`s or not
- produces the same output of [Michael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29714723/4453460)